# JavaScript: Instantiating a class from a JSON array

Tags: javascript, json, testcomplete

I have a TestComplete (UI testing) project which uses JavaScript, and I'm trying to store class references in JSON. It seems that my code isn't working, so I might have a conceptual misunderstanding of how JavaScript handles class references in JSON. Here's code which demonstrates my line of thinking:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.name = "ClassName";
  }
}

function print_name(str_name) {
  console.log(str_name);
}

let my_json = {
    "keyOne": [
        MyClass
    ]
};

let class_ref = my_json["keyOne"][0];
print_name(class_ref.name);
```

Is there a reason why the print_name function would fail to print the "name" property of the MyClass object?

Comment: You have to create an instance of the class...

Comment: let class_ref = my_json["keyOne"][0];

Comment: No, an actual instance: `"keyOne": [ new MyClass() ]`

Comment: Where are you actually using JSON? You’re just using a JavaScript object. JSON can’t hold functions.

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer : Yes there is a reason for that 
and the correct code should like this

```
let my_json = {
"keyOne": [
    new MyClass()
    ]
};
```

why ?

because you should store an instance of the class not the class itself 
and to do that in **Javascript** we use the **new** key word followed by the constructor function

BTW if you check this code

```
typeof MyClass
```

in the console you will get  **function** 
but its a new syntax comes with the ES2015 a new version of Javascript that make working with a lot of things easier 
and your code is the same as

```
function MyClass(){
this.name = "ClassName";
}
```

so this acts as a blueprint and to create an object you should use the **new** key word followed by the constructor
like this

```
let mySimpleClass = new MyClass();
```

now if you console

mySimpleClass.name 
you will git **ClassName**

note:- if you want to convert your **my_json** variable to actual Json
use this

```
JSON.stringify(my_json);
```

learn more :

[Working with Javascript Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

[JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)